# Problema invocar metodo java

Tags: java

Estoy realizando una pequeña aplicación para mi proyecto de clase y no se que hago mal:
Por un lado este es mi codigo de la clase:

```
package propiedadviewer;
   
public class Casa {
    String dir;
    int cp;
    int nh;
    int m2;
    
    public Casa (String dir, int cp, int nh, int m2) {
         this.dir = dir;
         this.cp = cp;
         this.nh = nh;
         this.m2 = m2;
         }
     public String getDir () {
         return dir;
         }
     public int getCp () {
         return cp;
     }
     public int getNh () {
         return nh;
     }
     public int m2 () {
         return m2;
     }
}
```

Y aqui tengo la clase main, desde la que creo el array de objetos e invoco los metodos en concreto he hecho una primera prueba para saber si iba bien con getDir, pero no me pinta el String dir del objeto en cuestion..., no sale nada en consola.

```
package propiedadviewer;

public class Principal {
    
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Casa[] casas = new Casa [5];
        casas [0] = new Casa ("Calle Ma", 28200, 4, 120);
        casas [1] = new Casa ("Calle Ola", 28150, 2, 90);
        casas [2] = new Casa ("Calle Poma", 28240, 5, 300);
        casas [3] = new Casa ("Calle Pata", 28280, 1, 40);
        casas [4] = new Casa ("Calle Pala", 28250, 10,900);
        
        casas[0].getDir();
    }
}
```

En que estoy fallando, para que el metodo no me devuelva la String dirección de el array casas [0]?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3):

Estás fallando en que no estás haciendo nada con el resultado que obtienes:

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
    Casa[] casas = new Casa [5];
    casas [0] = new Casa ("Calle Ma", 28200, 4, 120);
    casas [1] = new Casa ("Calle Ola", 28150, 2, 90);
    casas [2] = new Casa ("Calle Poma", 28240, 5, 300);
    casas [3] = new Casa ("Calle Pata", 28280, 1, 40);
    casas [4] = new Casa ("Calle Pala", 28250, 10,900);
    
    System.out.println("La dirección es " + casas[0].getDir());
}
```

Comment: Y yo esperando a que se me pintara automaticamente, sin un sysout.
Menuda empanada mental llevo, muchas gracias Pablo!

Comment: @AlvaroG si esta respuesta te ha ayudado, considera marcarla como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), para que futuros usuarios con tu mismo problema sepan que es correcta. Es ademas la forma adecuada de agradecer la ayuda que te han proporcionado.